# Getting cannot connect error using Selenium Webdriver in Java program (Firefox)

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

I am getting a strange error when trying to run my Java program with Webdriver.  I have a new PC so it could e thatt I am missing something.

Here is the console log [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/a/viddler.com/file/d/0B4ekmEoMnQYWUXZkTmMtNGVTZGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Please help us to help you by editing your post to add missing information: errors, code, things you've tried and that didn't work etc. Google Drive docs we don't have access to aren't any use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is resolved.  I just needed to download the latest selenium sand alone server.